# diffrent views according to if user is logged in or not

Tags: python, authentication, django-rest-framework

i am trying to filter the Tasks according to current user and i want to view all if no one is logged in

here is my views class:

```
class TasksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Tasks.objects.filter(Q(assigner=self.request.user)| Q(assignee=self.request.user))
        return queryset
    queryset = Tasks.objects

    serializer_class = TasksSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def perfrom_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(self, assigner=self.request.user.pk)
```

this do the job when a user is logged in .. what can i do to view all if no one is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.request.user
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    if not user.is_anonymous():
        queryset = queryset.filter(Q(assigner=user)| Q(assignee=user))
    return queryset
```

I suggest you to read some docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object